# How do you organize your sharepoint developments?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am starting to do a lot of sharepoint development lately, and some of the things that I have done and I dont like is to use sharepoint designer directly for things like pagelayouts, lists definitions, master pages, etc. 
From my point of view I think its more organized to do everything in Visual Studio.  In that way you can connect each solution to a source control database and deploy/retract/upgrade easier with scripts.

My idea is to create a vs solution like this:
1. One for list and content type defintions.
2. One for webparts.
3. One for branding

but maybe this approach has any disadvantage, what other approaches are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is going to be: it depends.

I do not think there is one best way to organize a Visual Studio solution or SharePoint solution packages. In the end, you need to find what works best for your organization and go with that.

The only guidance I have seen is from the SharePoint Online documentation:

> If the development team is designing a solution that requires more than 10 WSP files, the team should reconsider its architecture. It is difficult to manage and deploy so many WSP files within a single deployment window, and the solution risks rejection because of the complexity for SharePoint Online of managing it.
>
> A large number of solution packages (WSP files) that need to be tracked and managed pose a challenge for deployment. The more solution packages in a customization, the greater the possibility that something will not be installed correctly, the longer the solution will take to deploy, and the easier it is to mix incompatible versions of solution packages. We recommend that customers scrutinize their deployment plans and keep the number of solution packages to the minimum number needed for the project. Keep in mind that a solution package can contain several features, so there is no necessity to have one solution package for each feature.

And I would agree with this. You seem to be outlining 3 Visual Studio solutions and/or SharePoint solution packages for what really are 3 Features within a single SharePoint solution package.

I tend to create one Visual Studio solution for each project. For a very large project, that single Visual Studio solution might contain several projects where each represents a SharePoint solution package.

For Farm solutions, each SharePoint solution package will contain a number of Features and files that are all related in terms of functionality or application. If two or more SharePoint solution packages share common Features, I will put those shared Features into a separate solution package.

Sandbox solutions tend to be much smaller than Farm solutions. While my Farm solutions usually represent an application, my Sandbox solutions are more focused to solve one particular issue. So my Sandbox solutions usually only contain one Feature that does not rely on other custom Features or solutions.

As I said in the beginning, I do not believe there is one hard or fast rule. It is usually determined by the preferences and style of a particular development team. Try a couple different ways in the beginning and eventually you will find what fits your team best.